Using same inquiry design for two different landing pages
Hello there and hope all of you are doing great!
My client offers two services and the website have two different landing pages for this services.
First one is designed in light mode and CTA sends to the inquiry flow where customer should put info so my client can send the quote to the customer (Inquiry has 5 steps as there is solid amount of info needed for the inquiry).
Second service landing page is designed it dark mode as client want to distinguish this two services his company offers. Inquiry is pretty much the same (with some little redesigns) for this service also.
I am wondering if I could go with the light mode design for the inquiry for the second serice (with landing page in dark mode) or I need to make it also in dark mode so customer does not fill confused? Going with the same inquiry would definitely reduced the time and money costs of development.
Sorry for little longer explanation, hope you have some ideas :D
All the best!

Welcome to the site. There is little design in your question, though: "[in] dark mode as client want[s] to distinguish"... That sounds like there is no design rationale in choosing light/dark, which means we are the wrong people to ask :-(

What will you do if the client decides to create another service in the future?
I think you should strongly advise the client on a design that is going to work well short term and long term, so using light and dark mode for this is not a good idea.
The purpose of light/dark design styles is not intended to differentiate content on the website.
There are plenty of options like using different colours in the palette, in combination with symbols and images to do this much more effectively.
